# how we can shutdown hsqldb database in java

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb, jdbctemplate

i am using hsqldb as my database. i want whenerver my select query, update query execute it will shutdown a database. below is the method in which i need a code from which i can manually shutdown my database.

```
private void insertInitData(BasicDataSource dataSource, int lmexAdapterId, int lmsId) {
    try {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String lmexPostParam_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String inertQuery = "Insert into lmex_post_param (lmex_post_param_id, param_name, param_value) values (?,?,?)";
        String[] baseUrlParam = { lmexPostParam_id, "base_url", lmexPostingBaseUrl };
        jdbcTemplate.update(inertQuery, baseUrlParam);
        String lmexPostParamId2 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String[] postServiceParam = { lmexPostParamId2, "post_service_url", lmexPostingPostServiceUrl };
        jdbcTemplate.update(inertQuery, postServiceParam);
        String lmexPostParamId3 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String[] lmsIdParam = { lmexPostParamId3, "lms_id", lmsId+"" };
        jdbcTemplate.update(inertQuery, lmsIdParam);
        String lmexPostParamId4 = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String[] adapterIdParam = { lmexPostParamId4, "adapter_id", lmexAdapterId+"" };
        jdbcTemplate.update(inertQuery, adapterIdParam);
        //shutdown database by code
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the code must be replace in the place of comment "shutdown database by code".

help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just curious -- why would you do something like that?

Comment: @Nishan - The user must shutdown an in-process HSQLDB database before the application is closed but there is no need to shutdown an HSQLDB server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("SHUTDOWN");
```

Comment: Thank but i get it before you reply me. but thnk for replying

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to shutdown your database using java code.

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("SHUTDOWN");
```

it works