# HSQL Connection Error. Any insight?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm trying to connect to HSQL using java.  I'm using a tutorial to work with JDBC and hibernate.  It's the lynda tutorials.  Anyway, here's the code below:

```
package com.lynda.javatraining.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

    private static final String USERNAME = "dbuser";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "dbpassword";
    private static final String CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:hsqldb://data/explorecalifornia";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conn = null;
        System.out.println("A");
        System.out.println(conn == null);
        System.out.println(CONN_STRING);
        try {
            System.out.println("B1");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("B1-2");
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("B2");
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("B3");
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("C");

    }

}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
A
true
jdbc:hsqldb://data/explorecalifornia
B1
2014-06-27T15:26:27.430-0400  SEVERE  could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@76d682a[file =/data/explorecalifornia.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/explorecalifornia.lck (No such file or directory)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.openPersistence(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.lynda.javatraining.db.Main.main(Main.java:24)

B2
java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@76d682a[file =/data/explorecalifornia.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/explorecalifornia.lck (No such file or directory)
B3
C
```

Can anyone tell e what I"m doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: Does /data exist on your system? And, if so, do you have write permissions to this directory?

Comment: /data does exist.  It made the folder in the eclipse project.

Comment: The exception you posted shows it looking in /data (i.e. the absolute path and *not* the relative path e.g. {path-to-your-eclipse-project}/data). Maybe try jdbc:hsqldb:file://etc [more here](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html).

Comment: Interesting.  If I do use the absolute path it works out just fine, though the relative path doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So I think I just got it now.  The relative path now works if I remove the "//" before data.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

A database has a lock file `explorecalifornia.lck` that prevents communication. You should delete lock file and restart the database. This may happens from time to time when you accidentally shutdown the database or system.

See the syntax of the command used from the command line to invoke [shutdown](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html#shutdown-section). There's also an option [how to shutdown server in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298035/how-we-can-shutdown-hsqldb-database-in-java).

Comment: I only show two files, the .properties, and .script file with explorecalifornia as the name.  Where would the .lck file be?  Thank you for your help I appreciate it.